# why do onchange and onblur only work sometimes?

Tags: onchange, onblur

My form has a small number of fields where the user can add values like this one

```
<input name='extracost' type='text' size='25' id='extracost' value='$extracost' onChange='calculate();' >
```

Problem is that with onBlur or onChange only 'seem' to work once.  If the element extracost starts as 0 or null, for example, if I change it on form to 50, the function seems to work correctly and total increases by 50.  But if I set it back to 0, it does nothing.  If I set it again to -50 it will subsequently work.

If I set the extracost to 50, then 60, then 70, the total goes up by 180.

here is the relevant javascript

```
var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal").value;
var extracost = document.getElementById("extracost").value;
var total = Number(subtotal) + Number(extracost); 
document.getElementById("total").value = total;
```

I've read lots of threads here with a similar problem but none of the solutions have worked.

Comment: onChange='calculate();' can be substituted for onBlur='calculate();' to no effect.  onmouseup doesn't solve issue either

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have onBlur event in your source code.

In addition, try to parse the textbox value:

```
var subtotal = parseInt(document.getElementById("subtotal").value, 10);
var extracost = parseInt(document.getElementById("extracost").value, 10);
var total = (subtotal) + (extracost); 
document.getElementById("total").value = total;
```

I would think you are having the issue in Chrome. Finally, onChange and onBlur only work when your cursor goes off the textbox.

Comment: parseInt returns NaN

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was found by eliminating this

```
var subtotal = parseInt(document.getElementById("subtotal").value, 10);
```

and gathering all the individual form variables used to calculate subtotal, and simply recalculate it.